# Given a lat/lng coordinate, calculate the min and max lat/lng values for a 10 km area

Tags: google-maps, latitude-longitude

Lets say I have a lat lng coordinate and I want to place that at the center of a square that is 10km wide and then get the minimum lat/lng and maximum lat/lng.

Is there an easy way to do this that already exists?

Comment: How precise do you need the coordinates - just good enough for display, or for full-on GIS stuff?

Comment: It doesn't need to be hugely accurate - if its off by a km or two then that's fine.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If it doesn't need to be exact, it is pretty easy:

For the latitude, 1 km is 0.009 degrees (follows from the original definition of meter). Since your square is 5 km around the center, you just need to add and subtract 0.045 degrees from the center point.

For the longitude, it is slightly more complicated: Divide the above value with the cosine of the latitude.

In code:

```
lat_min = lat_center - 0.045;
lat_max = lat_center + 0.045;
long_min = long_center - (0.045 / Math.cos(lat_center*Math.PI/180);
long_max = long_center + (0.045 / Math.cos(lat_center*Math.PI/180);
```

(`Math.PI/180` is needed to convert from degrees to radians).

Beware: Does not work around the poles.

Answer (score 1):

How is the square oriented?  Parallel to the equator?  If so, then just do a bearing of 45 deg, 5km * sqrt(2) distance from your lat/lon to get the upper right corner.  Similar for the bottom left, use a bearing of  225 deg.

See **Destination point given distance and bearing from start point** at http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html

Comment: You mean 10 * sqrt(2) distance? Yes, that's what I meant in my comment about how accurately he needs this. In practice though the actual max/min lat/longs are going to vary at each corner - the max longitude value is actually going to be at bearing 135, but if you're approximating it to a square rather for display there's probably nothing in it.

Comment: Technically, it should be 5 * sqrt(2) if the square is 10km wide.  If you want the other corners, just add 90 deg to the bearings above.