# PHP MySQL: Query with Less Than AND Greater Than

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following mysql query in my PHP file:

```
$shopID   = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['shop_id']);
$latitudeCenter = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['lat_center']);
$longtitudeCenter = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['lng_center']);

$lat_min = $latitudeCenter - 0.045;
$lat_max = $latitudeCenter + 0.045;
$long_min = $longtitudeCenter - (0.045 / cos($latitudeCenter*M_PI/180);
$long_max = $longtitudeCenter + (0.045 / cos($latitudeCenter*M_PI/180);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM shops WHERE shop_id = '$shopID' AND lat >= '$lat_min' AND lat <= '$lat_max' AND lng >= '$long_min' AND lng <= '$long_max'";
```

For some reason the query is not running successfully. Is the above query valid?
Thanks

EDIT:

There is something wrong with the $long_min and $long_max calculations as when they are commented out, it works ok.

Here is the code I tried to conver to PHP:

```
lat_min = lat_center - 0.045;
lat_max = lat_center + 0.045;
long_min = long_center - (0.045 / Math.cos(lat_center*Math.PI/180);
long_max = long_center + (0.045 / Math.cos(lat_center*Math.PI/180);
```

What is wrong with my PHP?

Comment: What is the datatype of column `lat`?

Comment: Adding the error to your question would help out a lot. `echo mysql_error();` after you executed `mysql_query($sql);`.

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions for new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the [**red box**](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help to choose. If you care to learn, [here is good PDO tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: mysql_error() still returns a blank white page

Comment: Do you actually have data which can match your query?

Comment: @user1417302 Do an `echo $sql;` and use the query printed in mysql. See if that gives any results or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the MySQl's `BETWEEN` and **NEVER** use quotes for comparing numbers. So the query becomes:

```
$sql = "SELECT *
  FROM shops
  WHERE shop_id = $shopID
    AND lat BETWEEN $lat_min AND $lat_max
    AND lng BETWEEN $long_min AND $long_max";
```

Where, I have considered that `shop_id` column is auto-incremental number.

Comment: thanks this seems correct, shop_id is actually VARCHAR, however i'm still getting a blank white page. I'm thinking there is something wrong with the maths calculations

Comment: @user1417302 `Here is the code I tried to conver to PHP:`. Convert the code from where? and Why

Comment: From this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10398481/given-a-lat-lng-coordinate-calculate-the-min-and-max-lat-lng-values-for-a-10-km