# Using Greater than ( >= ) in URL App Inventor

Tags: php, mysql, url, app-inventor

I'm using this php code as part of App Inventor

```
$Techid = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_GET['Techid']);
$diffs = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_GET['diff']);
$values = mysqli_query($dbc, "SELECT * FROM CPETrack WHERE (Techid= '$Techid') AND (diff = '$diffs')");
```

The web url i need to parse over is:
`http://domainhere.com/custserv.php?id=1000&diff>=15`

The techid is defined in app inventor itself and so is the diff.

I can do this in the mysql DB
`SELECT * FROM CPETrack WHERE id=1000 AND diff>=15;` and it will return all items from the relevent id column and diff column greater than or equal to 15.

I'm unable to convert this to php thou to do the same job. How would I go about doing this?

Please bear in mind the actual diff value will be set within app inventor and I'm using `set url1 to` block in app inventor and `join` text block to create the web url and the php to give the result.

[image]

Comment: `$_GET['diff']` doesn't exist, it's `$_GET['diff>']` because URLs only recognise `=` as a separator between the key/value pair in the url

Comment: `$diffs = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_GET['diff>']);` This cannot be due to the fact that the `$_GET['diff'];` is the sql DB column name.

Comment: And now you're giving yourself `diff = 15` in your SQL query..... do a bit of basic debugging, like var_dumping your $_GET

Comment: The idea is to get all diff column values over 15 from the db and show the result. It works in the sql screen when debugging, just doesnt translate to php and then into a usable URL

Comment: I can see what the idea is. I've told you what both problems are. I've told you how to debug it. Do you expect me to write it for you as well?

Comment: No. But you are incorrect. I have debugged, it works in mysql, it works in php without the > sign. i can set the url to `http://...../custserv.php?id=1000&diff=15` and it will return all values AT 15 from the diff column. It needs to return all values greater or equal too 15. Ive added your amendments and surprisingly i got this result `Warning: mysqli_fetch_row() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in /home/a5666415/public_html/custcsv.php on line 28`

Comment: Have you var_dumped $_GET at all to see what it actually contains?

Comment: Have you actually read what ive asked for? The $_GET is getting values ive set from a sql db. The $Techid and $diff are values that are parsed over from appinventor spinner selector and put into a web url. the web url would be `...custcsv.php?Techid=[my value here]&diff=[my value here]` That works fine and gives me exactly what i require. all i need now to to get a `greater than or equal to` into the url that works. i can then sort the php. Having already tried encoding the > as %3E but to no avail. Thanks for your interest thou.

Comment: Yes I have read what you asked for: HAVE YOU DONE A [var_dump($_GET)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) TO SEE WHAT'S ACTUALLY BEING PASSED THROUGH TO YOUR SCRIPT? If should not contain a `diff` key when the url contains `&diff>=15`... that magic `>` will be treated as part of the key.... and if you can't be bothered to do basic debugging when you've been told what the problem is, then I can't be bothered wasting my time trying to help you

Comment: 'array(3) { ["Techid"]=> string(5) "13293" ["Type"]=> string(4) "SHUB" ["diff"]=> string(2) "15" }'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what about using **>=** in your php script like this

```
$values = mysqli_query($dbc, "... AND (diff >= '$diffs')");
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer was found at [PHP MySQL: Query with Less Than AND Greater Than](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11580608/)

Amended Php code to
`$values = mysqli_query($dbc, "SELECT * FROM CPETrack WHERE (Techid= '$Techid') AND (Type= '$cpe') AND (diff BETWEEN $diffs AND 100)");`

I can now set the $diff value from the `spinnerselection` and the listpicker returns values between $diff value and 100.