# Creating a bounding box from a latitude/longitude and a 'radius'

Tags: php, latitude-longitude

I have been looking for a piece of code (preferably in PHP) which can take a latitude, longitude and a plus/minus value (in Km) and return the minimum and maximum latitude and longitudes.

I can't seem to find anything which both explains what it does in simplistic terms as well as takes into account the 'bloated' curvature of the earth.

Can anyone help?

Comment: see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10398481/given-a-lat-lng-coordinate-calculate-the-min-and-max-lat-lng-values-for-a-10-km/10413685#10413685

Answer (score 1):

This is tricky because latitude/longitude is an angular quantity, whereas your radius distance is an incompatible linear quantity.

Here are some methods of solving it, in decreasing order of accuracy and increasing order of simplicity of coding.

1. Use a projection library to first do the calculations in projected coordinates (x,y) and then re-project back to (lat,lon). There is a php port of the well-respected [proj4 library](http://proj4php.sourceforge.net/), and I see [PEAR](http://pear.php.net/pepr/pepr-proposal-show.php?id=165) has a projection library too.
2. Approximate the Earth by an ellipsoid with WGS84 parameters. 
   See the accepted answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125144/how-do-i-find-the-lat-long-that-is-x-km-north-of-a-given-lat-long).
3. Approximate the Earth by a sphere and use spherical trigonometry.
   See the accepted answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/238260/how-to-calculate-the-bounding-box-for-a-given-lat-lng-location).
4. Use simple proportion of approximate conversion factors for your area of interest.
   See the accepted answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1253499/simple-calculations-for-working-with-lat-lon-km-distance).

I recommend no. 1.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why why you want to do this in pure PHP  but `MySQL` and `MongoDB` support geospatial indexing which has huge performance advantage over any pure PHP implementation.

I personal prefer the `MongoDB` version because it installed by default and you can easily serach by

- Near
- Radius
- Box
- Polygon
- Distance

Please See

- [Geospatial Indexing in MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Geospatial+Indexing)
- [12.16. Spatial Extensions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/spatial-extensions.html)

Comment: I am using CouchDB and Map/Reduce. Is there a similar way of implementing it?

Comment: Not by default  but you can use [GeoCouch](https://github.com/couchbase/geocouch/)

Comment: Also just found GeoCouch through Google, this is where things get complicated! I am using Cloudant which serve CouchDB to me.

Comment: So, I have found and setup a MongoDB service, do you know of a good PHP library that will let me interact with this service? (I am using MongoHQ)

Comment: YOu don't need mongoHQ  see https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-driver/downloads and download the default driver

Comment: I need a web server which I don't currently have access to, only a localhost machine.

Comment: This has nothing to do with your question above

Answer (score 0):

In order to make things easier, I have switched to MongoDB's system and am currently using MongoHQ's REST API to access the data with their geo APIs.